# Python KeyError only with Apache2 server (not with Django server)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

When I tested my Django application with 'manage.py runserver' no issue.
But, if I deployed same code by using Apache2 mod_wsgi (v3.3), KeyError happened from the below line. I'm using dpkt v1.8 to dissect PCAP file from web app.

Even worse, if I remove `self.ipaddr` line then KeyError happened from the `self.offset`.

```
def __init__(self, pcapfile, lastsec):
        self._pcap= dpkt.pcap.Reader(pcapfile)
        self.packet_count = 0
        self.ipaddr = None   # KeyError happened from here
        self.offset = -1
        self.lastsec = lastsec
        self.fragments = dict()
        self.gtp = False
```

Any hint for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: It will be useful if you post the error output, so we can see more details about the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Isn't it easier to use nginx and plup?

after installing plup, run the script by:

python ./manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8002

then do the nginx settings:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx

Comment: Not an answer to the question.

Comment: Plus they probably meant flup and not plup.